# How do I search for a type in .NET, disregarding the assembly version?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to maintain savefile compatibility between multiple versions of my program, but this causes problems with serialization, as the assembly qualified type name changes when I increment the version number, so Type.GetType() can't find it. Is there any way to search for a type disregarding the assembly version?

Comment: Serialization **doesn't force** you to have the same assembly version (even BinaryFormatter that keeps track of it will resolve to installed/current version). Moreover, if you're not doing something custom, you won't need to call GetType() directly (which BTW will resolve assembly with a different version too). If you tried and it doesn't work I suggest you post a small working example!

Comment: Most serializers(xml, json) don't require assembly version. try to avoid to use BinaryFormatter which indeed requires it.

Comment: @Adriano: If you have a strong name on your assembly, binary serialization does check the version and the public key of that type!

Comment: @toATwork of course! but if you change public key then you have a different assembly and it's unrelated to version (you may have same version but different public key or different versions and same public key - as it should be).

Comment: @Adriano as far as I understood just the version changes. public key stays the same

Comment: @toATwork yes, it's what I understood too. That's why he shouldn't have any problem with that (well...if he is using binary serialization he will have problems someday but this is another story...)

Comment: @Adriano you are totally right - I know what I am talking about cause I had the same problem as ekolis some time ago. The answer below is how we "solved" that issue

Comment: @Adriano Actually I am using custom serialization, since all of the off-the-shelf serializers I've tried couldn't handle some aspect or other of my data structures, or required convoluted configuration procedures.

Comment: The reason I'm saving the assembly qualified type name is because that seems to be the only way to reliably look up types without doing a bunch of manual parsing.

Comment: @ekolis if you're doing custom serialization then I simply suggest to do not serialize full type name. "MyClass, MyAssembly" (without version and publick key) will be resolved as required. Actually even fully qualified name should be resolved...

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure that when I serialized just "MyClass, MyAssembly" that Type.GetType() returned null. I'll have to try it again to be sure... perhaps it only works for built-in CLR types (i.e. those in mscorlib) and not those in my own assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out!

I had to use this overload of Type.GetType() to customize the resolution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332932(v=vs.100).aspx

I did it like so:

```
type = Type.GetType(typename,
    assemblyName =>
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == assemblyName.Name);
    },
    (assembly, typeName, caseInsensitive) =>
    {
        if (caseInsensitive)
            return assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.FullName.Equals(typeName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        else
            return assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.FullName == typeName);
    });
```

Note the comparison of GetName().Name, as opposed to FullName, for the assemblies. This is what enables comparison of only the actual names of the assemblies, and not their versions.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a type is not found the AssembyResolvedEvent is fired.

This event can be used to check your types loaded and return that type which has the same name but ignore the version number.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**EDIT**:
As this was some time ago it seems that I could not recall it all correctly.
Adriano was was correct. The AssemlyResolve ist just asking for the assembly.

So additionally a SerializationBinder is needed. This sounds like work, but is quite simple! I'll try to summarize:

```
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
  if (args == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name))
    return null;

  //if object was serialized with previous version .dll, deserialze with current version .dll (only relevant with strong names)
  foreach (Assembly ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
  {
    if ((args.Name.StartsWith("XYZ."))  // XYZ marks my namespace
      && args.Name.Contains("Culture=neutral") && args.Name.StartsWith(ass.FullName.Split(',')[0]))
      return ass;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Remark: this checks only for assemblies which are already loaded!

Your SerializationBinder:

```
  public class XYZSerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
  {
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
      Type curType = null;
      //if object was serialized with previous version .dll, deserialze with current version .dll (only relevant with strong names)
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyName) && assemblyName.Contains("Culture=neutral")
        && (assemblyName.StartsWith("XYZ.")))
      {
        string plainAssemblyName = assemblyName.Split(',')[0];
        Assembly ass = Assembly.Load(plainAssemblyName);
        curType = ass.GetType(typeName);
      }
      else
      {
        curType = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
      }
      if (curType == null)
      {
        return typeof(InvalidType);
      }
      return curType;
    }
  }
```

Now just use the binder!

```
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Binder = serializationBinder;
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
      storage = formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
    }
```

I hope this is what you want / need!

Comment: Well it can be used to load assembly (not types) without version information but...it's not required. Unless he forced a specific version or he's using some custom rule for binding then if you ask version 1.0 and you have 1.1 then it'll load 1.1 without errors.

Comment: @Adriano yes. Maybe I was a not clear enough. You can load an assembly as well. I understood it that way, that the assembly with the new version is already loaded. The serializers lookps for the old version and cannot find it. In that event handler you can search for the type yourself and return the one you think is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! This looks useful; my only concern is that in order to do the resolution manually, I'd have to parse the fully qualified assembly name that I'm saving off and strip out the relevant information. I was actually considering saving the type name in a custom format, but that would require just as much work in parsing it, so I'm not really sure which approach would be better. Parsing type names wouldn't be so much of a problem were it not for nested generic types, e.g. Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>. You can't just split on the commas to get the list of arguments!

Comment: @ekolis I did update the answer, hopefully it helps!

Comment: Oh, thanks! I think that will work - just one question. What if I have two assemblies loaded that contain types with the same namespace and name? How would I distinguish between the two? I don't think this actually occurs in my code, but I'd just like to be safe...

Comment: Actually, I'm using custom serialization code, so the binder bit might be irrelevant. However I think I can use the contents of your AssemblyResolve event handler in my serialization code to search for the types, in place of Type.GetType(). I'll have to see how that works out...

Comment: Hmm, not quite... I still need some way to split the assembly name out from the type name. I can't just split on commas, because the type name comes first, and it can contain commas itself it is a generic type. Also, regarding generic types, those themselves contain assembly names, so I'd need to parse them recursively...

Comment: Wait, did you say that this only matters for strong-named assemblies? I'll have to see if I can get by without strong-naming my assembly. I think I did this so I can pass objects from C# to IronPython in a sandboxed AppDomain, but I'm not entirely sure that's absolutely necessary... Actually, maybe it doesn't matter, because the CLR assemblies are strong-named, so if someone runs this program on a different version of the CLR, then it will break anyway...

Comment: @ekolis too much comments, I'll try to answer one by one: having the same classname in the namespace is IMO an error - how would you distinguish when programming?

Comment: @ekolis splitting of name should not be a problem, keep in mind: asdf.GetType().FullName + ", " + asdf.GetType().Assembly.FullName == asdf.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName

Comment: @ekolis yes, this only concerns strongly names assemblies/types. If no strong name is specified, the version is not checked either

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you can use assembly redirection therefore:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You should use a SerializationBinder to resolve types.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Please note that you probably will be better off using XML or DataContract serialization that do not save type information and are also much faster.